# Download percentage gives error

Tags: vb.net, math, download, httpwebrequest

I have a code where it can download a file but I stumble on this error ***"Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow"***. Here's the code:

```
    Dim nRead As Integer
    'To calculate the download speed
    Dim speedtimer As New Stopwatch
    Dim currentspeed As Double = -1
    Dim readings As Integer = 0
    theRequest.AddRange(nRead)
    Do

        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then 'If user abort download
            Exit Do
        End If

        speedtimer.Start()

        Dim readBytes(4095) As Byte
        Dim bytesread As Integer = theResponse.GetResponseStream.Read(readBytes, 0, 4096)

        nRead += bytesread
        Dim percent As Short = (nRead * 100) / length

        Me.Invoke(safedelegate, length, nRead, percent, currentspeed)

        If bytesread = 0 Then Exit Do

        writeStream.Write(readBytes, 0, bytesread)

        speedtimer.Stop()

        readings += 1
        If readings >= 5 Then 'For increase precision, the speed it's calculated only every five cicles
            currentspeed = 20480 / (speedtimer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)
            speedtimer.Reset()
            readings = 0
        End If
    Loop
```

It's stuck at

```
     Dim percent As Short = (nRead * 100) / length
```

Answer (score 0):

Click For Downloading Files in .NET With All Information: Progressbar, Download Speed, Supports Cancel and Resume

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17979/Downloading-Files-in-NET-With-All-Information-Prog

Comment: Currently I'm using these code to download a file and when the file reach 20971.22 kb it gives error Arithmethic operation resulted in an overflow

Comment: what was the actual size of the file?

Comment: 98508.39 kb and there are other files that is bigger than this file. I try change Dim nRead as integer to double and error code cannot convert system.double to system.integer32 comes out

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer

```
Dim percent As Short = nRead / Length * 100
```